# Is there a CSRF protection implemented in Boomla?

Tags: boomla

I want to implement a tool (a website that can edit a user's own websites) that receives uploads from the browser and stores them in a website specified in the request. However, I want to protect the user from other sites creating requests to my endpoint and doing dirty things with the user's data.

The industry standard for this is to include a randomized token in every rendering of the page, submit it together with the input data, and check the validity of the token on the server side before processing the submitted request.

Is there an automated mechanism for this in the Boomla framework, or is something like this planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented, no. Planned, yes.

Currently (v0.9.1), I believe Boomla does check the Referer header, but it stops there. So long, maybe you could implement a cryptographic solution yourself?

How pressing is the issue for you?

Consider that currently, side effects are not possible (eg. send data), thus data leaks are not possible, it won't cause data loss, since we have built in version control. (We are going to expose a casual version control mechanism that works automatically, without commiting, so you'll be backed up even without commiting.) Thus, in effect, your users are safe.

Please disagree if you think otherwise.

Comment: OK for me, I'm not planning anything too serious :) Thanks!